# What are the qualities of sound and playability of an SilverStar Harmonica?

Tags: harmonica

I recently bought on impulse an harmonica, however i'm wondering how good it is in terms of sound and ease of use considering i plan using it to learn to play.

It's a Hohner SilverStar Diatonic harmonica on C key.

If you need any more information let me know to edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hohner is generally a good quality brand, and good quality is generally equal to easy playing when it comes to diatonic harmonicas. The worst you can do as a beginner is to use a low quality harmonica that are subject to leaking air, which makes it difficult to get a nice sound.

Generally diatonic harmonicas are often used as beginners harmonicas, so the type you have found sounds like a good choice.

So even if I don't have personal experience with the exact model you have, I am pretty confident about saying that your Hohner is a good instrument to start on. And it will be a good instrument for a long time ahead.